# How can I change the text that is actually displayed by a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know if there is a JTextArea method that I can override to change what is displayed on screen?

I want to keep the contents of the field the same. Ie. If I set the text to "hello" and I call getText(), I wan't it to return "hello".

However, I wan't to be able to override what is displayed on screen (Eg. to replace with '*****')

Yes I know JPasswordField does this, but I need to use a JTextArea, and also would like fine control over what is displayed.

Any ideas? Is there a display method that I can override? Many many thanks if you have!!!

Comment: Why do you have to use a JTextArea but not a JPasswordField? JPasswordField is a subclass of JTextArea...

Comment: No it's not. It's a sublclass of JTextField. I need to override a JTextArea to make it work like a password field in the same way the JPasswordField overrides JTextField.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I modify a Java Swing JTextArea so that it looks like a JPasswordField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308518/can-i-modify-a-java-swing-jtextarea-so-that-it-looks-like-a-jpasswordfield)

Answer (score 0):

[Manipulating User Data at the Model Layer in Swing](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3509066)

> SUMMARY: Most of the graphical user
>   interfaces (GUIs) developed with the
>   Java Swing toolkit accept user input
>   and validate it. Swing is built on the
>   principle of the separable model
>   architecture, a version of
>   Model-View-Controller design where all
>   of the graphical components have
>   corresponding data model objects.

[Part 1: Model-View-Controller and Swing](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3336761)

```
Document doc  = new DefaultStyledDocument();    // MODEL object
JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea(doc);             // VIEW object 1
JTextArea ta2 = new JTextArea(doc);             // VIEW object 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But how does this actually help me change the text that is actually displayed on the screen for the JTextArea?